# Prove that $\forall m \in \mathbb{Z}: f(x+m)=f(x) \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, solution-verification, induction

I tried solving this problem for quite some time now but I think there must be a simple solution I am just not seeing so I would appreciate some kind of hint how to proceed.
**Problem:** Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous and $f(x+1) = f(x) \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that $\forall m \in \mathbb{Z}: f(x+m)=f(x) \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.
**What I've got so far:** I tried proving this via induction over $m \in \mathbb{N}$.
For $m=0$ we have $f(x+0)=f(x)$ which is obviously true. For $m=1$ the expression $f(x+1) = f(x)$ is true by definition.
Induction hypothesis: Assume $f(x+m)=f(x)$ or $f(x+(-m)) = f(x)$ to be true for an arbitrary $m$ and $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.
Induction step: $m \to m+1$
$$
f(x+(m+1)) = f(\underbrace{(x+1)}_{x'}+m) = f(x'+m) \overset{IH}{=} f(x') = f(x+1) \overset{Def}{=} f(x).
$$
Since we want to prove it for all whole numbers: $-m \to -(m+1)$
$$
f(x+(-(m+1))) = f(\underbrace{(x+(-1))}_{x'} + (-m)) = f(x'+(-m)) \overset{IH}{=} f(x') = f(x+(-1))
$$
And here is where I got stuck because I cannot simply apply the definition of the function here because it doesn't say anything about $f(x-1)$. I tried figuring out what it means though: We have $f(x+1)=f(x) \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$. So we can just define $x' = x-2$ and get $f(x'+1) = f(x') = f(x-2)$ but also $f(x-1) = f(x-2)$. But this seems to even contradict the statement I am trying to prove doesn't it?

Comment: In the last bit, you can set $x'=x-1$ and show that $f(x-1)=f(x)$. Where are you seeing a contradiction?

Comment: "it doesn't say anything about $f(x-1)$": yes it does: since $f(y+1)=f(y)$ for every $y$, applying this to $y=x-1$ you get...

Comment: Oh wow... thank you so much! This is just the part that was missing I guess. Don't know why I thought setting $x' := x - 2$ would do it and didn't try sth else.

Comment: $f(x)=f(x+1)=f(x+2)=f(x+3)=\cdots =f(x+m)$ for all natural $m$.